# Use Guice multibindings with assisted inject for the set members

Tags: java, scala, guice

I have a class `PluginManager` which accepts a `Set<Plugin>` using the Guice multi-bindings feature. However, the `PluginManager` has some runtime information that needs to be passed to the `Plugin` constructor.

This seems to be a perfect use-case for Guice assisted injection i.e. my `PluginManager` would have `Set<PluginFactory>` injected, where the runtime information is provided to each factory, resulting in the required `Plugin` instances.

I don't know the syntax to use in the `Module` however. The multibinder `addBinding` does not seem to have any facility to connect the result of `FactoryModuleBuilder`.

I can create my own custom Factory implementations and multibind that obviously, but is there a way to combine multibinder with assisted inject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gives you an example to do exactly what you want. Please note that scala's multibinder has a pending pull request that allows you to create the set binder in multiple places.

```
object Test {
  trait Plugin {
    def name(): String
  }

  object Plugin {
    trait Factory[+T <: Plugin] {
      def newPlugin(name: String): T
    }
  }

  case class MyPlugin @Inject() (@Assisted name: String) extends Plugin
  case class OtherPlugin @Inject() (@Assisted name: String) extends Plugin

  class PluginManager @Inject() (pluginFactories: Set[Plugin.Factory[Plugin]]) {
    for (factory <- pluginFactories) {
      println(factory.newPlugin("assisted injection"))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScalaModule {
      override def configure(): Unit = {
        val plugins = ScalaMultibinder.newSetBinder[Plugin.Factory[Plugin]](binder)
        plugins.addBinding().to[Plugin.Factory[MyPlugin]]
        plugins.addBinding().to[Plugin.Factory[OtherPlugin]]

        bindFactory[Plugin, MyPlugin, Plugin.Factory[MyPlugin]]()
        bindFactory[Plugin, OtherPlugin, Plugin.Factory[OtherPlugin]]()

        bind[PluginManager].asEagerSingleton()
      }

      def bindFactory[I: Manifest, C <: I : Manifest, F: Manifest](): Unit = {
        import net.codingwell.scalaguice._
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
          .implement(typeLiteral[I], typeLiteral[C])
          .build(typeLiteral[F]))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You can do a bunch of things depending on the style you want. For example you could make a generic addPlugin method (when a newer version of scala-guice is released) like this:

```
val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScalaModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bindPlugin[MyPlugin]()
    bindPlugin[OtherPlugin]()

    bind[PluginManager].asEagerSingleton()
  }

  def bindPlugin[T <: Plugin : Manifest](): Unit = {
    val plugins = ScalaMultibinder.newSetBinder[Plugin.Factory[T]](binder)
    plugins.addBinding().to[Plugin.Factory[T]]
    bindFactory[Plugin, T, Plugin.Factory[T]]()
  }

  def bindFactory[I: Manifest, C <: I : Manifest, F: Manifest](): Unit = {
    import net.codingwell.scalaguice._
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
      .implement(typeLiteral[I], typeLiteral[C])
      .build(typeLiteral[F]))
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I was close to this but didn't have a generic type on my Factory trait, and so Guice was telling me I couldn't bind each plugin because it had already been bound. This worked perfectly!

Comment: BTW, I did run into the issue you mentioned with scala-guice and Multibinder (https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice/issues/29) but the code in your referenced pull request fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I know it does! =) I wrote the pull request =).