# Binding same parameter to multiple implementations with Guice's MultiBinder and Asisstedinjection

Tags: java, guice

I have a set of validator classes that all extend a common abstract class, all with the same constructor

```java
public abstract class AbstractValidator {
    public AbstractValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Validator1 extends AbstractValidator {
    public Validator1(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }
}

public class Validator2 extends AbstractValidator {
    public Validator2(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }
}
```

I want the ability for Guice to

1. Know how to construct all of these validators, injecting the same DataSource into all of them
2. Inject all of the validators into a class using a [MultiBinder](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings)

Through some googling, it looked like I could use `AssistedInject`, but the problem is that if I wanted to do that, I would have to make a factory for every validator, which is a huge amount of boilerplate. Because they all have the same constructor, I feel like there must be a better way. My `DataSource` object is created outside of Guice, and I just want to bind it to all instances of `DataSource.class` in my `configure`.

One thing I'm willing to change is to have some kind of factory method that would allow me to create a validator from just a `DataSource`... I recognize my desire to use constructors might not be type safe.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514009/use-guice-multibindings-with-assisted-inject-for-the-set-members) looks almost like what I want, but it's in Scala, which I'm not familiar enough with to fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for AssistedInject.

You can bind you instance of `DataSource` like this:

```
DataSource dataSource = ...;
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
  @Provides @Singleton DataSource provideDataSource() { return dataSource; }
  @ProvidesIntoSet Validator provideValidator1(DataSource dataSource) { return new Validator1(dataSource); }
  @ProvidesIntoSet Validator provideValidator2(DataSource dataSource) { return new Validator2(dataSource); }
});

Set<Validator> validators = injector.get(new Key<Set<Validator>>(){});
```